# Various way to attach event with html by jquery

Tags: jquery

i have seen that people use various way to attach event with html element but i do not which one should when as per situation. if possible please discuss which pattern is best and also discuss which we need to follow based on what situation.

here is few snippet for attaching event by jquery

```
$(textbox).bind('focus blur', function () {
    //do something
});
var $textbox = $('input'); // (Use a $ to mark variables that hold jQuery objects
$textbox
    .on("focus", function () {...
    })
    .on("blur", function () {...
    });
$("textbox").bind('focus blur', function () {
    // your code
});
$('#any_button').live('click', function () {});
```

Comment: preferred method is to use `.on()`, because of consistency when you need to delegate event and BTW, jquery internally called it in all case (excepted ready handler which is a promise)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As jQuery documentation states, the [live-function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated.

[Bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) on the other hand is not, but the documentation states that you should use on instead.

So if u are asking which one to use, always use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).